# Change name of abstract

Tags: naming, abstract

I'm writing a document with and abstract and I've set the language to Spanish, and so the abstract environment displays the word "Resumen" instead of "Abstract". I want the opposite. I've tried

```
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Abstract}
```

And

```
\renewcommand{\abstract}{Abstract}
```

The first does nothing and the second displays the word Abstract but removes the bold font, puts it in the beginning of the line and the abstract text displays just after it, something like:

```
Abstract. This is the abstract...
```

How should I properly change it? The class document is `article`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This depends on the document class.  Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\abstract}{Abstract}` is of course wrong, since you have changed the `\abstract` command (or environment) completely

Comment: Is the abstract in english or spanish?

Comment: @Johannes_B Spanish, but the word Abstract is always used. This is for a project and I believe leaving the spanish word would be better just for consistency, but I have to use Abstract.

Comment: @Sverre The OP says that `\renewcommand\abstractname{...}` doesn't work the expected way. How is it a duplicate then?

Comment: @MyUserIsThis Please follow what Christian Hupfer requests and add a Minimal Working Example ("working" here means "can be compiled and shows the formatting error you deal with").

Comment: @Sverre It's not a duplicate, I already saw that question and clearly state that renewcommand was not working...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a guess of a working document, since there is no information on the document class so far.

Use the `\selectlanguage{english}` feature of `babel` for the abstract and change later on to `spanish`.

I assumed `article` as underlying class.

I've added some unneeded commands to show the language change.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents


\selectlanguage{spanish}

\section{\contentsname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is `scrartcl` version (with some 'improvements')

```
\documentclass[abstract]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\abstract}{\selectlanguage{english}}{}{}  % Switch automatically to english
\xapptocmd{\endabstract}{\selectlanguage{spanish}}{}{} % Switch back at end of {abstract}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents



\section{\contentsname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The class was article. And that solved my problem. I didn't know of the existence of `\selectlanguage`. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @MyUserIsThis: Alright. Thanks for accepting, but please, please, provide more information next time ;-)

Comment: I'll do in the future. I always use the article class so I thought these solutions were more or less universal. Thank you again.

Comment: I'd recommend setting the `abstract` environment inside an `otherlanguage` environment: `\begin{otherlanguage}{english}\begin{abstract} ... \end{abstract}\end{otherlanguage}` (freely add line breaks), rather than using `\selectlanguage`.

Comment: If your using KOMA, the even better solution would be: `\renewcaptionname{spanish}\abstractname{Abstract}`

Answer (score 26):

Change the name of the abstract *after* `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{myuseristhis}
\begin{abstract}este es un buen pato
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Important thing is, not changing the language to english just to get the abstract name right, as hyphenation pattern for english and spanish are different.

Comment: If you need to do this in the preamble (for instance if you want to include it to a separate class file), you can include `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{myuseristhis}}` to the preamble.
The `\AtBeginDocument{}` hook will take care of executing the code inside the `document` environment.

Answer (score 4):

Your first command has of course changed it but to the same title!

Check with this, you will see the difference

```
 \renewcommand{\abstractname}{Resumen}
```

Comment: This is a guess at the moment, as we do not have enough information

Comment: I think i got the question wrong! Sorry ignore my answer

Comment: We've to wait. My answer is a guess only at the moment too

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: I guess  that you have exactly answered the question.

Comment: I want to do the oposite. It displays Resumen because I've set the document in spanish (because I need all the rest of the keywords translated), but I want the word abstract in english.